# how to code this recursive grammar?

Tags: coding-style, grammar

I have the following grammar :

S -> S{S}S  | null

Here null means nothing to be there in place of S.
I need to generate all possible strings of 2n brackets generated by this grammar.
I have tried to code it but the program runs out of memory. Could someone please help me code this grammar for 2n number of brackets?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Could you post your code in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? I'm sure someone is able to point out why it throws an out-of-memory error.

Comment: This grammar is ambiguous...  `{}{}` can parse as either `null{S}S` or as `S{S}null`.  So any generative approach is likely to output `{}{}` twice.  Probably easier to just write a recursive-descent parser, feed it all 2^(2n) strings of 2n `{`/`}`, and print the ones that parse successfully.

Answer (score 1):

First, prove that this grammar generates all strings of *balanced* curly braces.

(Hint: Start by proving `S -> S{S} | null` generates all such strings.)

Then just write a function to generate all of those:

```
function generate(num_opens, num_closes, string_so_far, N)
    if (num_opens + num_closes == N)
        print string_so_far;
        return;
    if (num_opens > num_closes)
        generate(num_opens, num_closes+1, string_so_far . '}', N)
    generate(num_opens+1, num_closes, string_so_far . '{', N)

generate(0, 0, N)
```

This may or may not be in the "spirit" of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some psuedocode for you:

```
function grammar: S(string), n(int), generatedStrings(collection)
    if (|S| == 2*n)
        // Store in generatedStrings
        return
    else if (|S| > 2*n)
        return

    grammar(S + '{}', n, generatedStrings)
    grammar(S +'{'+ S +'}', n, generatedStrings)
    grammar(S +'{'+ S +'}'+ S, n, generatedStrings)
    grammar('{'+ S +'}'+ S, n, generatedStrings)
    grammar('{'+ S +'}', n, generatedStrings)
    grammar('{}'+ S, n, generatedStrings)
```

Then you'll just need some mechanism to make sure you don't add duplicates to the set of generated strings. I'd use a set-type data structure (in other words, a structure that only allows one of each value to be stored) for that.

Comment: I do not think this works because the S's can be different, but this code requires them to be the same.  For example, `{}{{{}}}` matches this grammar, but I do not think your code will ever output it.

Comment: Sure it will. If the six recursive calls are numbered 1..6, that string is generated by the following sequence: 5->5->5->6.

Comment: OK bad example :-).  Try `{{}}{{}}`.

Comment: OK, but...can the S's really be different? Granted, it's been a few years since I did anything with grammars, but I don't recall them working that way.

Comment: Pretty sure "S" means anything matching an "S", even if it appears twice.  But I could be wrong